# Getting nearby input value in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I want to **get hidden value on click of button** .It gives me undefined .Any help will be apprecited .Adding **js fiddle** to answer will be more helpful using my code.

*html code here*

```
<form method="POST" action="#">
    <input type="hidden" name="carid" class="carid" value="10">
    <input type="button" name="transfer" id="transfer" class="btn btn-default" onclick="transfercars()" style="margin-top:22px;" value="transfer">
    </form>
```

in jquery i have

```
function transfercars() {
    var carid = $(this).parent().find("input[type='hidden']").val();
    console.log(carid);
    var carid = $(this).prev('.carid').val();
    console.log(carid);
}
```

Comment: First post your full code with html and what have you try for button click.

Answer (score 2):

you can do like below.

```
<form method="POST" action="#">
    <input type="hidden" name="carid" class="carid" value="10">
    <input type="button" name="transfer" id="transfer" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-top:22px;" value="transfer">
</form>

$("#transfer").on("click", function () {
    var carid = $(this).parent().find("input[type='hidden']").val();
    console.log(carid);
    var carid = $(this).prev('.carid').val();
    console.log(carid);
});
```

Comment: can you plz add a fiddle so that it will helpful and i have more than one form with multiple input hidden and button.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using `this` there, `this` refers to the `window`.

You want something like this:

```
(function(){
    document.getElementById("transfer").onclick = function() {
        var val = this.previousElementSibling.value;
        console.log(val);
    }
})();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hvu0bb23/)

It can be done easily in JavaScript, no need for jQuery :)

For multiple forms, you can do this.

```
(function(){
    var el = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-default');
    for (var i=0;i<el.length; i++) {
        el[i].onclick = function() {
            var val = this.previousElementSibling.value;
            console.log(val);
        }
    }
})();
```

You need to change the `id=` to `class=` or just create a new class for all the `input type='button'`s.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hvu0bb23/1/)

Comment: how to do it for multiple forms . like i asked in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You could their names for that. And instead of a onclick attribute, I would bind a function to it.

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="#">
    <input type="hidden" name="carid" class="carid" value="10">
    <input type="button" name="transfer" id="transfer" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-top:22px;" value="transfer">
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$('[name="transfer"]').on('click', function() {
    var carid = $('name=["carid"]').val();
    console.log( carid ); 
});
```